# returning a value using REST

Tags: rest, tomcat

I am getting errors when I am trying to return values using REST. The error is:

> A HTTP GET method, public  -  should not consume any entity.

This is my class:

```html
public class StockManagement {


 ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

 ArrayList<Integer> stockLevel = new ArrayList<>();
 
 @GET
 @Produces("application/xml")
 public String addItem(String item) {
 if(items.contains(item)) { // returns true is item is exists else false
  String r = "Item is already in list";
  String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" +  r;
  return  "<StockManagementService>"+ "<div>" + result  + "</div>" +"</StockManagementService>";
 }
 else {
  String r = "Item has been added successfully";
  String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" + r;
  items.add(item); // add item to inventory
  stockLevel.add(0); // set the number of stock for the item in inventory
  return "<StockManagementService>" +"<div>" + result  + "</div>"  +"</StockManagementService>";
  
 }
 }
 
 @GET
 @Produces("application/xml")
 public String setStock(String item, int stockLevels) {
  if(!items.contains(item)) {
   String r = "Item is not in the inventory";
   String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" + r;
   return "<StockManagementService>" + result + "</StockManagementService>";
  }
  else {
   int index = items.indexOf(item);
   stockLevel.set(index, stockLevels);
   
   String r = "Set stock has been complete successfully";
   String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" + r;
   return "<StockManagementService>" + result + "</StockManagementService>";
   
 
  }
 }
 
 @GET

 @Produces("application/xml")
 public String addStock(String item, int numItem) {
  if(!items.contains(item)) {
   String r = "Error, Cannot add item";
   String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" + r;
   return "<StockManagementService>" + result + "</StockManagementService>";
  
  }
  
  else {
   int index = items.indexOf(item);
   String r = "Successfully added stock";
   String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" + r;
   return "<StockManagementService>" + result + "</StockManagementService>";
   
  }
  
  
 }
 
 @GET
 
 @Produces("application/xml")
 public String removeStock(String item, int numItem) {
  if(items.contains(item)) {
   int index = items.indexOf(item);
   int val = stockLevel.get(index);
   val = val - numItem;
   stockLevel.set(index, val);
   
   String r = "Successfully removed item.";
   String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" + r;
   return "<StockManagementService>" + result + "</StockManagementService>";
  }
  else {
   String r = "Item is not in the inventory";
   String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\")" + r;
   return "<StockManagementService>" + result + "</StockManagementService>";
  }
 }
```

This is the error shown on eclipse terminal:

```html
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.setStock(java.lang.String,int), should not consume any entity.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.addStock(java.lang.String,int), should not consume any entity.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.removeStock(java.lang.String,int), should not consume any entity.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.addItem(java.lang.String), should not consume any entity.
  SEVERE: Consuming media type conflict. The resource methods public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.addStock(java.lang.String,int) and public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.setStock(java.lang.String,int) can consume the same media type
  SEVERE: Consuming media type conflict. The resource methods public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.removeStock(java.lang.String,int) and public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.setStock(java.lang.String,int) can consume the same media type
  SEVERE: Consuming media type conflict. The resource methods public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.addItem(java.lang.String) and public java.lang.String com.crunchify.restjersey.StockManagement.setStock(java.lang.String,int) can consume the same media type
```

I cannot figure out what this error means, obviously it has to be the way I am returning, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No promises, but I think the WARNING is trying to remind you that, in HTTP, `GET` doesn't take a message body.  So `String item` should probably be encoded into the URI itself, which might mean a @QueryParam or @PathParam annotation.

SEVERE is trying to tell you that there are multiple methods that are all trying to be mapped to the same route.  That is to say, they are all mapped to the same URI with the same method and the same application type, so how is the routing logic supposed to choose between them.

That might mean that you need to specify different paths for each, or that you should have only one annotated method that has the logic to choose which implementation to use.